# jQuery delete all table rows except first

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery, how do I delete all rows in a table except the first?  This is my first attempt at using index selectors.  If I understand the examples correctly, the following should work:

```
$(some table selector).remove("tr:gt(0)");
```

which I would read as "Wrap some table in a jQuery object, then remove all 'tr' elements (rows) where the element index of such rows is greater than zero".  In reality, it executes without generating an error, but doesn't remove any rows from the table.

What am I missing, and how do I fix this?  Of course, I could use straight javascript, but I'm having so much fun with jQuery that I'd like to solve this using jQuery.

Comment: Anybody knows why the given code is not working ? I also have problem when putting filter selector in remove function

Comment: Now that I understand this better, the code above doesn't work because $(some table selector) selects only the table element, not any of its children, so there are no 'tr' elements for the remove function to find.  Using the find function searches for matches among the children of the table element.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831334/jquery-selector-all-but-the-first/18322370#18322370

Answer (score 549, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("someTableSelector").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
});
```

Comment: What if i want to remove table rows except first and seconde?

Comment: @user594166 use gt(1) instead of gt(0).

Comment: From the jQuery website:
`Because :gt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :gt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(index) instead.`

I would recommend using $("#mytable > tr").slice(1).remove();

Comment: your code didn't work for me.. i changed gt(0) to gt(1) and this worked.

Answer (score 119):

I think this is more readable given the intent:

```
$('someTableSelector').children( 'tr:not(:first)' ).remove();
```

Using children also takes care of the case where the first row contains a table by limiting the depth of the search.

If you had an TBODY element, you can do this:

```
$("someTableSelector > tbody:last").children().remove();
```

If you have THEAD or TFOOT elements you'll need to do something different.

Comment: re: do something different.... this works: `$('someTableSelector > tbody:last > tr:not(:first)').remove();`

Comment: to remove all children I had to use double quotes. Didnt recognise it otherwise. `$("#tasks").children().remove();`

Answer (score 52):

Another way to accomplish this is using the empty() function of jQuery with the thead and tbody elements in your table.

Example of a table:

```
<table id="tableId">
<thead>
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>some</td><td>content</td></tr>
    <tr><td>to be</td><td>removed</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the jQuery command:

```
$("#tableId > tbody").empty();
```

This will remove every rows contained in the tbody element of your table and keep the thead element where your header should be. It can be useful when you want to refresh only the content of a table.

Comment: This is probably going to have the best performance of all the solutions offered, and is very elegant.

Answer (score 40):

If it were me, I'd probably boil it down to a single selector:

```
$('someTableSelector tr:not(:first)').remove();
```

Comment: Agree, but more specic it must say: $('someTableSelector tbody tr:not(:first)').remove();

Answer (score 30):

Your selector doesn't need to be inside your remove.

It should look something like:

```
$("#tableID tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

Which means select every row except the first in the table with ID of tableID and remove them from the DOM.

Comment: I agree.  In my case, the table object had been previously selected.

Comment: To Remove all rows except the first one :- 
        $("#tableID tr:gt(1)").remove();

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#table tr').slice(1).remove();
```

I remember coming across that 'slice' is faster than all other approaches, so just putting it here.

Comment: Some it didn't work for me. The accepted answer seems to do the trick.

Comment: `gt` is deprecated, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Consider a table with id `tbl`: the jQuery code would be:

```
$('#tbl tr:not(:first)').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

To Remove all rows, except the first one (except header), use the below code:

`$("#dataTable tr:gt(1)").remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way :

```
$("#mytable").find($("tr")).slice(1).remove()
```

-first reference the table
-get the list of  elements and slice it and remove the selected elements of the list

Answer (score 0):

-Sorry this is very late reply.

The easiest way i have found to delete any row (and all other rows through iteration) is this

$('#rowid','#tableid').remove();

The rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#p-items").find( 'tr.row-items' ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

wrapped in a function:

```
function remove_rows(tablename) { 
    $(tablename).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();        
}
```

then call it:

```
remove_rows('#table1');
remove_rows('#table2');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly

```
$("#myTable tbody").children( 'tr:not(:first)' ).html("");
```

Comment: Yeah, that was already posted multiple times before. Anything new?

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the following way in my case and working fine

```
$("#compositeTable").find("tr:gt(1)").remove();
```