# Rendering an html table with ajax, JQuery, and render :partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is my question.  I want to create a table with a specific header row that looks like this

```
<table>
<tr class="table-header"> <th></th><th> Name </th><th> Location </th></tr>
..data..

</table>
```

The problem comes when i want to do an ajax populate of the table rows.  I have tried a couple options.  Basically my app knows where to insert the data using a selector like #table-data.  It will update fine, but overwrite the table header, or insert it all in one column, or put it above the header etc.  I have tried doing it with a div, `<p>`, `<tr>` etc. but it never seems to work out right.

My action looks like this:

```
def multi_search

     @profiles = Profile.find(:all) do
           first_name =~ "%#{params[:profile][:first_name]}%" if params[:profile][:first_name].present?
           last_name  =~ "%#{params[:profile][:last_name]}%" if params[:profile][:last_name].present?
           city  =~ "%#{params[:profile][:city]}%" if params[:profile][:city].present?
           state  =~ "%#{params[:profile][:state]}%" if params[:profile][:state].present?                
           type      =~  "%#{params[:profile][:type]}%"      
           paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:rows]      
           order_by "#{params[:sidx]} #{params[:sord]}"
       end

      render :partial=> "search/search_results", :collection => @profiles, :as=>:profile  
   end
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
$("#ajax_search_form").ajaxForm({target: '#provider_search_results'})
```

and my partial looks like this:

```
<tr>
 <td class="table_user_image"><%= image_tag profile.avatar.url(:small) %></td>
 <td class="table_user_name">
  <%= link_to_if(profile.user.role=="Provider", profile.full_name, { :controller => "profiles", :action => "show_public_provider",    :id=>profile.id}) do
       link_to(profile.full_name, { :controller => "profiles", :action => "show_public_student", :id => profile.id })
     end %></td>
 <td class="table_user_location"> <%= profile.city %>, <%= profile.state %> </td>

</tr>
```

In any case, I guess I need to render some static text before I get to the collection, and I'm not sure how to do it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE:  I am using jrails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `.ajaxForm()` call you can handle the response yourself.  Instead of using the `target` option you will have to handle the response by specifying a `success` [option with a function](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) that would do the following:

- Remove everything but your header row
  ([similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370013/jquery-delete-all-table-rows-except-first)) `$("#MyTable tr:not(.table-header)").remove()`
- Append the successful response to the
  table in question. `$("#MyTable").append(response)`

The other option would be to [render a partial](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html) that contains your header row and also renders your original partial with your collection.  A partial that renders another partial.