# jQuery selector - all but the first

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a small jQuery selectors question, I have the following html:

```
<div class="member-info first"></div>
<div class="member-info"></div>
<div class="member-info"></div>
```

I want to hide (using jQuery) all the divs that holds the "member-info" class, but not the one holding the "first" class, any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery select all except first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first)

Comment: Duplicate of either [all-elements-but-the-first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2259393/673991) or [all-elements-not-in-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4614120/673991). Either way, this question is particularly confusing naming the class of the first element "first". So answers include `':not(:first)'` and `':not(.first)'` and even `':not(first)'`!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('.member-info:not(.first)').hide();
```

This uses the [`not-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude elements with the `first` class.

Or if the purpose of the `first` class is simply to identify the first, then do this instead:

```
$('.member-info').slice(1).hide();
```

This uses the [`slice()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method  to return a set starting with the second match.

Comment: +1 slice() is going to be way faster because it's just removing an element from an array rather than having jquery check the class on each element again.

Comment: @Keltex: I agree. As long as the `first` class is always on the first match in the set, doing a slice will be the way to go.

Comment: @Keltex true, but the clearer one should be chosen, as class selection isn't likely to make any noticeable impact. (As always when related to performance, profile before and after)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).  For example:

```
$(".member-info:not(first)").hide();
```

If first is really always the first child, try

```
$(".member-info:not(member-info:first)").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".member-info:not('.first')").hide();
$(".member-info").filter(":not('.first')").hide();
$('.member-info').not('.first').hide();

$(".member-info:not(:first)").hide();
$(".member-info").filter(":not(':first')").hide();
$('.member-info').not(':first').hide();

$(".member-info:not(:eq(0))").hide();
$(".member-info").filter(":not(':eq(0)')").hide();
$(".member-info").not(":eq(0)").hide();

$(".member-info:not(:lt(1))").hide();
$(".member-info").filter(":not(':lt(1)')").hide();
$(".member-info").not(":lt(1)").hide();

$(".member-info:gt(0)").hide();
$(".member-info").filter(':gt(0)').hide();

$(".member-info").slice(1).hide();
```

All possible ways that come to my mind.
I also made [JavaScript performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/fastest-jquery-selector-all-except-first) where you can find some unexpectable results.

All of this samples work with v1.10.* of jQuery.

Most times this one is the fastest `$(".member-info").slice(1).hide();` and looks like relevant, not brainstormed answer

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but you could skip the first matched element using gt.

For example:

```
$('div.member-info:gt(0)')
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: Thanks @Jon- this one helped me out a good bit. Not sure why the others weren't.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue as well. However, I did not conveniently have a class named `first` marking my element for exclusion. Here was the solution I used for the selector in the context of this example:

```
$('.member-info:not(:first)');//grab all .member-info except the first match
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.member-info').not('.first').hide();
```

Using [`not()`](http://api.jQuery.com/not/).

Answer (score 0):

how about `$('.member-info').not('.first').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

`@AuthorProxy`, `@David Thomas` *and* `@Maximilian Ehlers` all suggest `$('.member-info').not('.first').hide();` in their answers which is a very fast, and very readable solution.

Because of the way jQuery selectors are evaluated *right-to-left*, the quite readable `".member-info:not(.first)"` is actually slowed down by that evaluation.

A fast and easy to read solution is indeed using the function version `.not(".first")` or even just `.not(":first")`:

e.g.

```
$(".member-info").not(".first").hide();   // Class selector
```

or

```
$(".member-info").not(":first").hide();   // Positional selector
```

**JSPerf of related selectors:** http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-select-all-expect-the-first-one/6

`.not(':first')` is only few percentage points slower than `slice(1)`, but is very readable as "I want all except the first one".