# jQuery - Replace all but first of class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

### Original Question

**Aim**

Using jQuery, get every element with the `.intro-portfolio` class. If the element is not the first one, replace it with `""` (nothing, blank, null bytes).

**What I've Done**

Searching around, I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831334/jquery-selector-all-but-the-first?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first) and I've tried to apply them to my situation. The simplified code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".intro-portfolio:not(:first-child)").each(function() {
        $(this).repalceWith("");
    });
});
</script>
<body>

<p>Test this is the control</p>

<p class="filter">This is the first</p>

<p class="filter">Second</p>

<p class="filter">Third</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Which, of course, doesn't work (can you tell I'm not a javascript/jQuery developer? I bet you're cringing from the syntax rules broken there).

How would you implement this?

**Context**

Tumblr theming - not relevant to the question, but it explain why I won't know what element the class will be applied to - it could be an `img`, or an `iframe` etc.

---

### Updates

<strike>**HUGE thank you to everyone that answered!** Evidently such a simple question only has one real way of doing it, but thank you for all answering! Up votes for all.</strike>

**Update 1:** Upon trying the solution, I've found that while it removes the element(s) from display, they're still loading.

Here's my implementation:

```
<html>
<head>
 ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 ...
    /* Remove HTML for all but first portfolio on home page */
    $(".intro-portfolio").slice(1).remove(); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

But when I view the source, the elements are still present. Isn't what the third code excerpt on the [docs page](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) is saying is that the elements shouldn't load or be present?

Take a look at the [development site](http://nchpmndev.tumblr.com) for the actual full code.

Comment: Yea, the example has a dumb mistake of wrong classes in it :D

Comment: Regarding your update: The source code will always show the HTML received by the server. To inspect the actual DOM tree, you have to use developer tools. The whole HTML converted to DOM first, and then the JavaScript is executed, modifying the DOM.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But when I (in Chrome) use the inspector, all the images (from multiple posts) etc. are still being loaded.

Comment: Well, I guess the browser starts downloading the images before you remove the elements and might not abort the download when they are removed. Maybe one of these help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+prevent+loading+images

Comment: Most modern browsers look ahead as they parse the DOM tree to find out what resources will be needed and pre-fetch them (this can include images and script files) see: http://www.igvita.com/2012/06/04/chrome-networking-dns-prefetch-and-tcp-preconnect/

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831334/jquery-selector-all-but-the-first/18322370#18322370

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` only selects an element **if and only if** it is the first child of its parent.

Your HTML does not contain `.intro-portfolio` elements, but if you meant the `.filter` elements to be them, then none of them is the first child of `body`. The first `p` element without a class is the first child.

It seems you want:

```
$(".intro-portfolio").slice(1).remove();
```

This will reduce the selected elements to all but the fist one and removes them.

**Reference**: [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), [`.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/szdk2/)

Comment: Also, there's nothing with the class `intro-portfolio` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.slice` method to pick a subset of the matched results, in the example below it will select all but the first item (the index is zero based).

The `.remove` method removes the matched element from the DOM and will also tidy up any event handlers etc attached with jQuery.

```
jQuery('.intro-portfolio').slice(1).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".intro-portfolio").not(":first").each(function() {
    $(this).bar();
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/PW3wt/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing here that's not in the other answers really, but this is the simplest form of what you're trying to do:

```
$('.intro-portfolio:not(:first)').remove()
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped me with a related problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".intro-portfolio:not(:first-child)").html("");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('.intro-portfolio:not(:first-child)').remove();
});
```

This maybe?