# I want to be able to choose the second or third li not just the first

Tags: jquery, selector

I tried using .not ("li.level-2") to show the second li .. no luck

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Collapse everything but the first menu:
$("#VerColMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
//$("#VerColMenu > li > a").not("li.level-2").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
// Expand or collapse:
$("#VerColMenu > li > a").click(function() {
    $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
   });
```

Comment: $('li.level2, li.level3') assuming each one has it's own class

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first

Comment: i inserted the class '<li class="level-2">' but no luck

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831334/jquery-selector-all-but-the-first/18322370#18322370

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the "a" tag instead of the "li" tag. If you want to select all "li" tags but the first try

```
$("#VerColMenu li").not(":first").each(function (){
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks for help but i think i narrowed down my issue ... i want to select multiple li> > a elements .. not just one as .not(":first") does ... maybe the first two or three ... it will vary .. but that is the main question ...

Comment: 'not(":eq(0),:eq(0)")' this kind of worked ... not sure if it is ideal

Comment: doesn't seem to be (ideal). Could you provide some of your HTML and mark the parts you would like to (not) select?