# Clear table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I call the function loadTable the first time, the information is displayed correctly, if I call the function again the information is displayed twice in the HTML page (one below the other).

Try deleting the information before the for loop with:

```
$("#tabla").remove();
$("#tabla").empty();
```

But the information is not deleted.

HTML:

```
<div id="divTabla"><table style="width:100%" border="1" id="tabla"></table></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadTable(datos) {
for (var i = 1; i < datos.length; i++) {
    d+= '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Host+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Time+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Country+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].City+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Isp+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Latitude+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Longitude+'</td>'+    
    '</tr>';
}
$("#tabla").append(d);
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code or how do I delete the information correctly?

Edit:

When I called the methods, I do it as follows:

```
function cargarTabla(datos) {
//Using only one at a time    
$("#tabla").empty(); //Doesn't work
$("#tabla").remove(); //The table is never displayed
for (var i = 1; i < datos.length; i++) {
    d+= '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Host+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Time+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Country+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].City+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Isp+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Latitude+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Longitude+'</td>'+    
    '</tr>';
}
$("#tabla").append(d);
}
```

Variable declaration d: It is declared in the same js file where the loadTable function is located, in the following way (It is the header of the table):

```
var d = '<tr>'+'<th>Host</th>'+'<th>Time(ms)</th>'+'<th>Pais</th>'+'<th>Ciudad</th>'+'<th>ISP</th>'+'<th>Latitud</th>'+'<th>Longitud</th>'+'</tr>';
```

Comment: Instead of using `$("#tabla").append(d);` you can use `$("#tabla").html(d);`

Comment: Have you tried using `$("#tabla td").empty()`?

Comment: @arielnmz  Yes but it does not work

Comment: Don't use `$("#tabla").remove()`, because that would remove the table itself. I'd have thought `$("#tabla").empty();` would work - can you provide a demo showing that it doesn't? Or try `$("tabla tr").remove()`.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053924/3196753.  `$("#tabla > tbody").empty();` Note, `tbody`, not `tr`.

Comment: @Panther Funciona correctamente con .append y .html pero el problema persiste.

Comment: Show where you call empty in your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery delete all table rows except first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370013/jquery-delete-all-table-rows-except-first)

Comment: @epascarello I edit the question to show how I make the call of the methods

Comment: well $("#tabla").remove(); removes the table.... not just the children.

Comment: WHERE do you define `d`?

Comment: @epascarello I edit the question

Comment: well there is your problem, that is why you should provide your full code to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is NOT with empty() not working. The issue is you use the variable `d` and you never reset it so it holds the values form the previous time.

```
function loadTable(datos) {
  var d = ""; // <--------
  for (var i = 1; i < datos.length; i++) {
    d+= '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Host+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Time+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Country+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].City+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Isp+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Latitude+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Longitude+'</td>'+    
    '</tr>';
  }
  $("#tabla").empty().append(d);
}
```

Comment: You are my hero, thank you very much, this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will remove the table. Call just [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) on the first line within the function loadTable. Also the variable 'd' was never declared, or it was declared out of the code you posted and never gets reset. Define d within the function to load the table and set it to empty. also you are starting your for loop at 1, start it at 0 if you do not want to exclude the first row.

```
loadTable([{Host: 'host', Time: 'time', Country: 'country', City: 'city', Isp: 'isp', Latitude: 'latitue', Longitude: 'longitude'}]);

function loadTable(datos) {
$("#tabla").empty(); 
var d = '';
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    d+= '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Host+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Time+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Country+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].City+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Isp+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Latitude+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+datos[i].Longitude+'</td>'+    
    '</tr>';
}
$("#tabla").append(d);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the last line of the function to this

```
$("#tabla").empty().html(d);
```

Comment: I didn't vote, but isn't `.empty()` a method? Also, the OP said they tried both `.empty()` and `.remove()` already.

Comment: Doesn't work, the information is displayed correctly but in the second call it starts to accumulate without cleaning the previously loaded.